# Stripe subscriptions: Modify when period ends instead of now

Tags: stripe-payments

*Context*: There is a Stripe plan "Starter". The customer subscribes to the "Starter" plan. Within a subscription period the user wants to up- or downgrade the subscription (in my case: the quantity will be increased or decreased). Programmatically I want to achieve this with a subscription update.

*Problem*: Stripe wants to make the update immediately. But I want to have it changed at the end of the period.

*Alternatives*:

- I saw this Stackoverflow asking exact the same question, but is six years ago -> [Stripe: downgrade a user at "period end"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820212/stripe-downgrade-a-user-at-period-end#). The proposed solutions are not really reflecting the desired solution and also do not work for me.
- I saw that Stripe has a subscription schedule API. Is this probably related to the problem solution?

I'm relly looking forward for (high-level) solutions to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I discussed with the Stripe support channel:

> I understand that scheduling is not the best fit for you, as you'd
>   have to release the schedule once the update is made so the new
>   subscription rolls over, and this doesn't cancel the subscription, but
>   start a new one.
>
> What you could do, is to cancel the first subscription at_period_end,
>   and then start the next one when the event
>   customer.subscription.deleted comes through:
>   https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-customer.subscription.deleted
>
> If you don't want to use Webhooks, you can also cancel at period end
>   and then generate the new subscription at the same time using the
>   billing cycle anchor
>   https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-billing_cycle_anchor.
>   This will only work though for subscriptions with the same interval,
>   or if the second subscription interval is shorter than the first.

I implemented the webhook solution. It works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to update the subscription details at the end of the current period. In that case, you may want to use the subscription webhook events mentioned [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/lifecycle#subscription-lifecycle)

"When the subscription period elapses, `invoice.created` event is sent, indicating the creation of a draft invoice."

"About an hour after the invoice is created, it is finalized (changes are no longer permitted), and an `invoice.finalized` event is sent."

So you can listen to that `invoice.created` event and then [update the subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update).